# obtener selectedvalue de un combobox en capa negocio

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

Hola buenas tardes me gustaria ver si alguien me puede apoyar con un tema en el combobox, lo que pasa es de que cuando lo lleno en la capa de presentacion esta de esta forma

CAPA PRESENTACION

```
    private void ListarArea(){
CN_Employed object=new CN_Employed();
cmbArea.DataSource = objemploy.ListarArea();
            cmbArea.DisplayMember = "NameArea";
            cmbArea.ValueMember = "IdArea";
}


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            try
            {
                CN_Employed objemploy = new CN_Employed();
                objemploy.InsertEmployed(
                    txtNEmpleado.Text, txtName.Text, txtFirsName.Text, txtLastName.Text,
                    txtNss.Text, txtRfc.Text, txtCurp.Text,DtNacimiento.Text, txtEmail.Text,
                    txtDireccion1.Text, txtDireccion2.Text, txtCalle.Text, txtMz.Text, txtSm.Text,
                    txtStatus.Text,DtContratacion.Text,cmbArea.SelectedValue);
                MessageBox.Show("Se inserto correctamente");

            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("no e pudo insertar los datos por:"+ex);
            }
        }
```

CAPA NEGOCIO, en la capa de negocio es en donde convierto todos los campos que son int pero estoy teniendo problemas con el valuemember del combobox, porque si lo convierto directamente de la capa de presentacion si me agarra de esta forma convert.toint32(cmbArea.selectedValue), pero lo quiero hacer desde la capa de presentacion. les pongo como lo hago desde la capa de negocio.

CAPA NEGOCIO

```
public void InsertEmployed(
            string NEmployed, string Name,
            string Firstname, string Lastname,
            string Nss, string Rfc, string Curp, string DateNaci,
            string Email, string Direccion1, string Direccion2,
            string Calle, string Mz, string Sm, string StatusEmp, string DateIngr,
            string IdArea)
        {
            obEmployed.InsertEmployed(
                Convert.ToInt32(NEmployed),Name,Firstname,Lastname,Nss,Rfc,Curp,DateNaci,Email,
                Direccion1,Direccion2,Calle,Mz,Sm,StatusEmp,DateIngr,Convert.ToInt32(IdArea));
        }
```

Comment: Deja ver si te entendí, tu lo que quieres es guardar el valor del combobox cuando seleccionas algún valor del mismo

Answer (score 0):

Una pregunta estas llenado el combobox con datos desde sql ?
o es una lista? Porque podrias usar la propiedad cmbArea.SelectedItem;

Comment: Si, lo que pasa es de que estoy manejando tablas relacionales, y en el cobobox saldria el id y por eso en el DisplayMember uso el nombre del campo y ValueMember ya es el que guardo en la consulta de mi form